# Not getting the Cookie while make next.js api hit to receive the cookie value from server component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

This is my getAccessToken Route handler:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export async function GET(request: Request, response: Response) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const theme: any = cookieStore.get("accessToken");
  return NextResponse.json({ token: theme, message: "hello" });
}
```

And this is my /home server component where i'm calling this api and suppose to get the response:

```
"use server";

import React from "react";

const page = async () => {
  const accessToken = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/getaccessToken");

  if (accessToken) {
    void accessToken.json().then((data: any) => {
      console.log("data >> ", data);
    });
  }
  return <div>HOME PAGE!</div>;
};

export default page;
```

in response i got the value { message: 'hello' } but not getting the token . can anyone have any clue what's going around here ?

here i want when i hit this getaccessToken route handler i will get the acessToken in response which i'm not getting currently

Comment: Do you understand what you wrote? The server component is trying to read cookie from the request and return it back in response. Are you sure the cookie is already set? If the request don't have the cookie, you wont get anything back either. You are not setting any cookie in above code.